# How to set a value at moduleEN - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, counter

I've this code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Controller is
port (
    CLK : in std_logic;
    OutENABLE : out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    ModuleRESET : in std_logic;
    ModuleENABLE : in std_logic
);
end Controller;

architecture Controller_archi of Controller is
    signal Counter : integer range 0 to 4200 := 0;

    begin
        process (CLK, ModuleRESET)
        begin
            if ModuleRESET = '0' then
                OutENABLE <= (others => '0');
                Counter <= 0;
            elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
                if ModuleENABLE = '1' then
                    Counter <= Counter + 1;
                    case Counter is
                        when 0 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "001";
                        when 450 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "010";
                        when 900 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "100";
                        when 1350 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "001";
                            Counter <= 0;
                        when others =>
                    end case;
                else
                    OutENABLE <= "000";
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

end Controller_archi;
```

But it's not working like I need.

What I need:

- When `ModuleENABLE` goes '1' instantly `OutENABLE` goes "001"  and not at first `rising_edge(CLK)` **(Now, in this code, if ModuleENABLE goes '1' OutENABLE doesn't change from "000" to "001", it change to "001" after first rising_edge(CLK))**
- Counter go up when `rising_edge(CLK)` and `OutENABLE` it's updated every `CLK` event. **(Now, in this code, counter go up when rising_edge(CLK) but OutENABLE it's updated when rising_edge(CLK) and not when CLK goes up and goes down)**

So I've modified code to do that:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Controller is
port (
    CLK : in std_logic;
    OutENABLE : out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    ModuleRESET : in std_logic;
    ModuleENABLE : in std_logic
);
end Controller;

architecture Controller_archi of Controller is
    signal Counter : integer range 0 to 4200 := 0;

    begin
        process (CLK, ModuleENABLE, ModuleRESET)
        begin
            if ModuleRESET = '0' then
                OutENABLE <= (others => '0');
                Counter <= 0;
            elsif ModuleENABLE = '1' then
                if rising_edge(CLK) then
                    Counter <= Counter + 1;
                end if;
                    case Counter is
                        when 0 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "001";
                        when 450 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "010";
                        when 900 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "100";
                        when 1350 =>
                            OutENABLE <= "001";
                            Counter <= 0;
                        when others =>
                    end case;
             else
                 Counter <= 0;
                 OutENABLE <= "000";
             end if;
        end process;

end Controller_archi;
```

Now code work like I need in ModelSim, but when I synthesize it or compile it and simulate again it doesn't work.

My question is:

- What it's wrong with second code and how I can fix it?
- If I can't fix second code how I can modify first code to work like I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What it's wrong with second code and how I can fix it?

Your synthesis tool is fussy about how the clock and reset lines are connected. You have to use a structure like:

```
        if ModuleRESET = '0' then
           ...
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
```

or the synthesis tool cannot recognise the clock and reset lines.

> If I can't fix second code how I can modify first code to work like I need?

You need to move "OutENABLE" outside of the first process, and into a process of its own. From what you've said, OutENABLE should not be a register - it should be a combinatorial function of Counter, ModuleRESET and ModuleENABLE. Try this.

```
    process (CLK, ModuleRESET)
    begin
        if ModuleRESET = '0' then
            Counter <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            if ModuleENABLE = '1' then
                Counter <= Counter + 1;
                case Counter is
                    when 1350 =>
                       Counter <= 0;
                    when others =>
                       null;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (Counter, ModuleRESET, ModuleEnable)
    begin
        OutENABLE <= "000";
        if ModuleRESET = '1' and ModuleENABLE = '1' then
            case Counter is
                when 0 .. 449 =>
                    OutENABLE <= "001";
                when 450 .. 899 =>
                    OutENABLE <= "010";
                when 900 .. 1349 =>
                    OutENABLE <= "100";
                when others =>
                    OutENABLE <= "001";
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Comment: I didn't explain well what I need from this code. The first code is working but not how I need. I've updated in my question what I need(you can find it in Strong), can you please check it again?

Comment: I get this two errors:
Multiple non-tristate drivers for net OutENABLE(2 downto 0) in Controller; Unresolved tristate drivers for net OutENABLE(2 downto 0) in Controller;
When I try to compile the code.

Comment: That means there are assignments to OutENABLE in both processes. Sorry. My fault. Corrected it.

Comment: Now the code is working. But I've an error in simulation. When for example OutENABLE is at state "010" it sometimes randomly goes to "000" then to "100" then back to "010", in a time of 1ns.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. OutENABLE is now generated by some combinatorial logic, but you don't get an immediate answer when the counter increments: there is still a propagation delay, and this accounts for what you see in the simulator, and the temporarily invalid state (a "glitch"). The way to avoid that is to make OutENABLE into a register, like your initial solution, in which case, OutENABLE won't change until a clock edge is reached.

Comment: There is a way to solve this problem in some way in your code?

Comment: I don't think so, it's an inherent limitation of the problem. You either make OutENABLE into a register, and then there's a single clock cycle delay when you change ModuleEnable, or you have OutENABLE as the output of a combinatorial function, in which case there are glitches when the counter ticks over. The best choice just depends where the signal is going.